# solving parameters of beta distribution , given mean and variance , using scipy

Tags: sympy

I have 'mu' and 'variance' calculated from data and I am trying to find parameters of Beta distribution

```
import sympy as sy
mu = sp.mean(univariate_samples[3])
var = sp.var(univariate_samples[3])
alpha = sy.symbols('alpha')
beta = sy.symbols('beta')
mu = alpha/(alpha+beta)
var = (alpha*beta)/(((alpha+beta)**2)*(alpha+beta+1))
sy.solve([mu*(alpha+beta)-alpha,var*((alpha+beta)**2)*(alpha+beta+1)- 
(alpha*beta)],[alpha,beta],[1, 1])
```

I get the following error
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "Symbol") to list

Answer (score 1):

This is not what **Sym**Py is for: it's for symbolic manipulations, not for solving some system of equations with floating-point parameters obtained from data. You get an error because `[1, 1]` does not belong in SymPy's solve, there is no "starting point" for symbolic solutions. But before that, the code was deeply flawed with `mu` and `var` being assigned twice (the second assignment wipes out the previous one, these are Python assignments, not equations).

Bottom line is, use a solver from SciPy when you need a **numeric** solution of a problem.

```
from scipy import optimize
mu = 0.6
var = 0.2
def f(x, mu, var):
  alpha, beta = x[0], x[1]
  return [alpha/(alpha+beta) - mu, (alpha*beta)/(((alpha+beta)**2)*(alpha+beta+1)) - var]
rv = optimize.root(f, [1, 1], args=(mu, var)).x
```

which finds the solution `[0.12, 0.08]`

---

By the way, none of this should be done to begin with: to fit a distribution to data, one should use [`fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html) methods from `scipy.stats`, which take the entire data set into account. Finding the shape parameters by equating the mean and variance to the sample mean and variance is a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you for the answer when i replace mu = 890.3643690444383 and var = 120121.91231564592 i.e. from my data then i do not get the solution, the solution give the same array as the initial guesses. am I missing something? Also, I am using this approach as I am trying to fidn the parameters using method of moment approach rather than MLE approach

Comment: The beta distribution is supported on the interval [0,1]. If you want numbers between 0 and 1 to have average 890, I can't help you.